# Escaping single quotes in postgres/python

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql

In making some slow code run more efficiently, I ran into a snag with escape characters.  The original code (which works) was something like this:

```
            sql = f"""INSERT INTO {schema}.{table} 
                  (seg_id, road_type, road_name) 
                  VALUES ({s_id}, '{road_type}', %s);"""

            # road_name may have an apostrophe. Let the execute() handle it. 
            cur.execute(sql, (road_name,))
```

This query ran many thousands of times, and the execute statements make the code sluggish due to communicating with a remote server. I would like to get a series of sql statements and execute them all at once, something like this:

```
            sql += f"""INSERT INTO {schema}.{table} 
                  (seg_id, road_type, road_name) 
                  VALUES ({s_id}, '{road_type}', '{road_name}');\n"""
```

The sql statement is not executed immediately, but is "stacked" so that I can execute a collection of sql statements in a single `cur.execute(sql)` which happens later.  However, since it does not have the `road_name` as an argument in the execute statement, it fails when there's a road name with an apostrophe (like `Eugene O'Neill Drive`).

What is a viable alternative?

*NOTE:  The query is in a function that is called from multiple processes.  The {variables} are being passed as arguments.*

Comment: https://www.psycopg.org/docs/extras.html#psycopg2.extras.execute_batch

Comment: @snakecharmerb - I'm afraid that will be less than optimum because the execute_batch function would not have access to the individual `road_name` params.  The sql statements are compiled in one function and executed in another after all the code runs. I suppose I could possibly save the statements as tuples and construct the single "big and complex SQL with %s %s params" in the latter function...  Worth a shot, I guess.  Thanks.